# JQuery : Get div defined in same table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have an HTML table created dynamically using an MVC application and the output of the table is as shown below:

In the `onclick` event of the edit button I want to show `divText` and hide `divLabel` of the same row using jQuery.

I have tried to get `divLabel` as shown below:

```js
function EditRecord(elem) {
  var divlabel = $(elem).closest('tr').children('td div#divLabel');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="divLabel">
        value 1
      </div>
      <div id="divText" style="display: none">
        <input type="text" value="value 1" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="edit" onclick="EditRecord(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="divLabel">
        value 2
      </div>
      <div id="divText" style="display: none">
        <input type="text" value="value 1" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="edit" onclick="EditRecord(this);" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're pretty close. There are two issues:

1. Your HTML is invalid. You cannot reuse the same `id` for multiple elements. You can use a class instead:

   ```
   <tr>
       <td>
           <!-- Note 'class' rather than 'id' below -->
           <div class="divLabel">
               value 1
           </div>
           <!-- Note 'class' rather than 'id' below -->
           <div class="divText" style="display: none">
               <input type="text" value="value 1" />
           </div>
       </td>
       <td>
           <input type="button" value="edit" onclick="EditRecord(this);" />
       </td>
   </tr>
   ```
2. `closest` is right, but `children` isn't. You want [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) instead, because the `div` isn't an immediate child of the row.

So assuming you change your HTML as per #1, we'd use `find` with a class selector for #2:

```
function EditRecord(elem) {
    var divlabel = $(elem).closest('tr').find('div.divLabel');
}
```

Comment: Agreed that I cannot reuse the same **id**. Your solution also works just perfect. But I have a question just for knowledge that is it a good practice to set the class="divLabel" even we have not defined class? I know it will not throw any exception.

Comment: It is fine to set a class that is not defined in any css file.  You can use it in JQuery as a type (like an ID).  Avoid using html id where possible, use css classes instead.  The benefit comes where you want to same functionality applied to more than one element, just give them the same css class.

Comment: @SpiderCode: Yes, that's absolutely fine (quite common, in fact). The class attribute is an HTML and DOM thing, not a CSS thing. CSS has class *selectors*: Selectors that work according to the HTML class. We frequently talk about "CSS classes," but that's not really accurate. (Amusingly, there was recently a link-post on http://css-tricks.com about this, but I can't find it now...) Think of it this way: Can you use a `div` even if you don't have any CSS selectors that target `div` elements? :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :  Agreed. Thanks for such a useful information.

Answer (score 3):

Try This one It should work for me

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function EditRecord(elem) {
    var chg = $(elem).closest('tr').children('td').siblings(':first-child');
    chg.find('div:first-child').hide();
    chg.find('div:nth-child(2)').show();
        }
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: good one. But in future If I have to put some other div between this two and I have implemented this solution then I will have to change JS method as well.

Comment: Dont change whole js code only change this two line  to this 
chg.find('div#divLabel').hide();
chg.find('div#divText').show();

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `onclick="EditRecord(this);"`, delete that out.  Doing it that way couples your javascript to your html which you can avoid using jQuery.

In jQuery do it like this

```
$("input[type='button'][value='edit']").click(function(event) {
    var row = $(event.target).closest('tr');
    row.find('.divText').show();
    row.find('.divLabel').hide();
});
```

*Note change `divText` and `divLabel` to css classes because you can't have two id's in HTML with the same name.